# why is the tag in backbone.js view rendering all of the model attributes into itself

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, handlebars.js

I am working with backbone.js and i am trying to understand if i am doing something wrong or is this how backbone should behave.

i am building a table, for that i have 2 templates
the first one is all the container and `<thead>` information which are irrelevant for the question.

then i am rendering the collection of items into rows. with this view:

> ```
>    MYAPP.Menu.ItemView = Backbone.View.extend({
>     tagName: 'tr',      
>     template: template('menu-item'),
>     initialize : function(modelItem) {
>     this.model = modelItem;
>     this.model.on('all', this.render, this);
>     },
>     render : function() {
>         var html = this.template(this.model.toJSON());
>         this.$el.html(html);
>         return this;
>     }
> });
> ```

this is the template for menu-item:

> ```
>   <script type="text/x-mustache-template" id="menu-item-template">
>             <td>{{title}}</td>
>             <td>{{description}}</td>
>             <td>{{price}}</td>
>             <td>{{status}}</td>
>             <td></td>
>     </script>
> ```

the output that i am getting inside the `<tbody>` tag is this:

> ```
>      <tr id="1" title="title1" price="price1">
>             <td>title1</td>
>             <td></td>
>             <td>price1</td>
>             <td></td>
>             <td></td>
>     </tr>
> ```

and so on.
**SO HERE COMES THE QUESTION**

Why is all the data stored inside the `<tr>` tag as attributes? i don't want that. why is it there?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're most likely initializing your view like this:

```
new MYAPP.Menu.ItemView(someModel);
```

This is incorrect, the correct way is to pass a model in an `options` object using the key `model`:

```
new MYAPP.Menu.ItemView({model:someModel});
```

The fact that the model attributes are being set as the element's attributes is just a bit of a unlucky coincidence in naming. Internally `Backbone.Model` stores its values in a property called `attributes`. `Backbone.View` on the other hand accepts an option called `attributes` in the options argument, and copies that over to `View.attributes`, which in turn sets those as attributes on the root element.

There are some special properties which are copied to the view automatically: `id`, `cssClass`,  `el`, `model` and `collection`, just to name a few. Because a model is just an object, calling `new View(model)` is equivalent to `new View({id:id, attributes:attributes, ...})`, and that causes the curious effect you're seeing.

So looking at your constructor code, it should look like this:

```
initialize : function(options) {
   this.model = options.model;
   this.model.on('all', this.render, this);
}
```

But because Backbone takes care of setting some of the View's options for your, including `model`, you don't strictly speaking even need to set `this.model`:

```
initialize : function(options) {
   this.model.on('all', this.render, this);
}
```